# Проблема подключения Sql Server к Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Проблема вот в чем. Есть MS sql server Manager studio и MS sql server 2012. Хочу подключиться к базе через MS Visual Studio 2010. Знаю, что при подключении необходимо выбрать источник данных SQL server, но его нет. Есть только эти источники. Подскажите пожалуйста, как подключиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: а именно  Database First а если база пустая то можно и  code first

Comment: Что Вы так пугаете человека своими аббревиатурами? У вас отсутствует драйвер ODBC. Пример установки тут https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-how-to/configuring-the-sql-server-odbc-driver-add-a-data-source?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Какая редакция Visual Studio? Какова конечная цель (зачем подключаться к БД через VS имея Management Studio, которая делает то же самое более удобно)?